# Get all the replies for multiple tweet ids and usernames

Tags: python, twitter

I am using Twitter API and I am trying to get all replies of multiple tweets' ids and usernames where tweets_ids and usernames are arrays. The main issue is appending all the replies within one index of "replies" array.
The following is my executed code.

```
for x, y in zip(tweet_ids, usernames):
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,q='to:'+y).items(numtweet):
             if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
                  if (tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str==x):
                      replies.append(tweet)
for tweet in replies:
     print(tweet.text)
```

where x is for tweet_ids and y is for usernames

Comment: what is `numtweet`? You are using it in second line.

Comment: @AndrewMcGuinness Sorry, its number of the returned tweets from search_tweets ``` numtweet = 50```

Comment: @AndrewMcGuinness I have removed it from the code, it works perfectly now!! Thank you so much for your help